# Count by Self Joining same table where one field is empty but another has value

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, case, self-join

I have a table that contains two sets of GPS coordinates, ones supplied by the customers the other captured by our field device.

The table's name is customer, the field names are as follows:

ID

Latitude [Data from Customer]

Longitude [Data from Customer]

GPSLatitude [Data from field device]

GPSLongitude [Data from field device]

1. I would like to count all such rows where **both** Latitude and
   Longitude are either blank or contain value=0.
2. Then count all GPSLatitude, GPSLongitude whose ID equal to those records which were counted in #1 and which are not empty or do not contain value=0

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  For instance, is `id` unique?

Comment: @GordonLinoff the Id is unique.

Comment: @DaleK I did the sum with case statement and tried to self join the table which did not work. Unfortunately, the query which I thought I saved on the server somehow did not save correctly.

Comment: @DaleK here was my query which I tried: 

SELECT sum(CASE 
   WHEN C.lat = ''
    THEN 1
   ELSE 0
   END) count_nulls,
   sum(CASE 
   WHEN CD.GPSLatitude <> ''
    THEN 1
   ELSE 0
   END) count_not_nulls
FROM Customer C (Nolock)
Left Join customer cd (nolock) on Cd.CustomerId=c.CustomerId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select count(*) cnt1, 
    sum(case when gpslatitude <> 0 and gpslongitude <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) cnt2
from customer 
where (latitude is null or latitude = 0)
  and (longitude is null or longitude = 0)
```

The query filters on customer longitude and latitude that are `null` or equal to `0`. `cnt1` gives you the count of such records. Then `cnt2` computes how many record in the resultset have both device coordinates neither `null` nor `0`.

Comment: Thank you @GMB this is the solution, I was incorrectly trying to do a self join whereas a simple where clause would have done the trick as your solution did.